# Looping React components with arrays vs objects

Tags: loops, reactjs, nested-loops

I'm trying to get to nested values in React and I'm getting an error.

I've separated the React components into pieces I want to loop over, but I'm thinking the issue trying to loop over objects vs arrays.

```
const TableRow = value => (
  <tr>
    <td>${value}</td>
  </tr>
);

const TableBody = ({ day }) => (
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{day}</td>
    </tr>
    { /* Repeats for each */ }
    {Object.keys(day).map(value => {
      <TableRow
        value={value}
      />
    })}
  </tbody>
);

const Table = ({ year }) => (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>{Object.keys(year)}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    { /* Repeats for each day */ }
    {Object.keys(year).map(day => (
      <TableBody
        key={day}
        day={day}
      />
    ))}
  </table>
);

const FullTable = ({ inputData }) => {
  return (
    <div>
    { /* Repeat table for each year */ }
    {inputData.map(year => (
      <Table
        key={year}
        year={year}
      />
      ))
    }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Given some sample data like:

```
const inputData = [
  {
    2017: {
      'Jan 1': [123.00, 123.99],
      'Jan 12': [123.98],
      'Feb 1': [123.00, 123.99],
      'Feb 2': [123.00, 123.99],
      'Feb 12': [123.98, 123.22],
    },
  },
  {
    2016: {
      'Jan 1': [123.00, 123.99],
      'Jan 12': [123.98],
      'Feb 1': [123.00, 123.99],
      'Feb 2': [123.00, 123.99],
      'Feb 12': [123.98, 123.22],
    },
  },
];
```

But I just get the following error: 
 Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {...})

I've created a [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/99Z4OyGP)

Comment: Each React component has to return exactly one root element. Your `FullTable` is returning multiple elements with no valid root element.

Comment: just wrap your repeat table code with div like <div>{inputData.map(year => (
      <Table
        key={year}
        year={year}
      />
      ))
    }</div>

Comment: Said in a different way, you need a parent component encapsulating all your tables.

Comment: Actually, my FullTable _does_ have one root element. I just removed it to post on SO. I've edited the above question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle out of this?

Comment: @AftabKhan Edited question to add CodeSandbox example

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your scenario on my local computer, using the code from the codesandbox link.

I did not get the error you mentioned, instead I got:

> flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key,
>   `[object Object]

The issue is exactly explained by the error message: both Table components have the same key, namely "object".

You are calling map on your inputData, which means that the argument passed to the map function is the 'year object', not the year number itself (however you seem to understand this, as you are passing the object down to Table correctly). These objects, when passed as a key of a component resole to the value "object" and thus your keys are actually equivalent.

You can solve the issue by generating a unique value from your year object and passing that as the key, ie:

```
JSON.stringify(year)
```

This solution is not elegant, and not safe; it would not work in cases where you had the exact same data (year object) corresponding to different years.

I would consider redesigning your data structure and having year as property of the objects, rather than the index (I'm not a big fan of associative arrays). As a result your key could simply be something like 'yearData.year'